# Naming a nested list and remove duplicate rows within the lapply(...) parenthesis (How to remove redudant <- (arrow))

Tags: r, list, nested

`as` here is a full_joined dataframe of nested list, which contains files from 9 folders, each having 8-11 csv files.

I have successfully arranged a nested list such that:

`as[[1]]` is a full-joined dataframe of folder `as1`
`as[[2]]` is a full-joined dataframe of folder `as2`
.
.
.`as[[9]]` is a full-joined dataframe of folder `as9`

using `lapply`

Here is my full code:

```
as <- data.frame()
df <- data.frame()
dfs <- data.frame()

data_dir <- "C:/Users/thepr/Documents/data/as"
num_fu <- 1 : 9
pat <- paste0(data_dir, num_fu)

as_list <-lapply(pat, function(x) {
  files <- list.files(x, pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)
  names(files) <- str_sub(basename(files), 1, 6)
  Reduce(full_join, lapply(files, read.csv))
})


#This is what I have tried
names(as_list) <- paste0("as", num_fu)
as <- Reduce(full_join, as_list)
as <- as[!duplicated(as.list(as))]
```

1. I want to name a nested list, so that

```
>names(as_list)
as1 as2 as3 ... as9

>names(as_list[[1]])
as1
>names(as_list[[2]])
as2
.
.
.
>names(as_list[[9]])
as9
```

2. I want to get this part of the code, which is outside the `lapply` inside `lapply(...)` or something less redundant.

```
names(as_list) <- paste0("as", num_fu)
as <- Reduce(full_join, as_list)
as <- as[!duplicated(as.list(as))]
```

Thank you.